# Parsing Date Format to specific culture

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I live in south Africa culture en-ZA, our date formats are inputted in format `dd/mm/yyyy`

I have a view that accepts a model:

```
public class UserInfoModel
{
    public DateTime DateOfBirth{get;set;}
    // some other properties here
}
```

When a user inputs the date ie: `04/15/1981` the datetime i get in my post method is 15 April 1981, however, when the following date is inserted `15/04/1981` the DateOfBirth property in the model returned is `null`

Is there a way i can change the way that the date is being parsed globally(throughout my application)

I added to my web.config the following:

```
<system.web>
  <globalization culture="en-ZA" uiCulture="en-ZA"/>
</system.web>
```

But it does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: Which model is null? UserInfoModel?

Comment: updated the question... only the DateOfBirth property in the model is null

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try to add this to your GlobalAsax.cs (located in your App_code directory)

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CultureInfo cInfo = new CultureInfo("en-ZA");
    cInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MM-yyyy";
    cInfo.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "/";
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cInfo;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cInfo;
}
```

Comment: works like a charm... thanx, strange that the entry in the web.config makes no difference

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Extension Methods 
e.g.

```
public static class StringExt 
{
    public static DateTime ParseToDateTimeMyWay(this string iString)
    {
        DateTime dt;
        DateTime.TryParseExact(iString, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
        return dt;
    }
}

"04/15/1981".ParseToDateTimeMyWay();
```